# Change video aspect ratio metadata

Tags: windows, video, aspect-ratio, media-player-classic, media-info

I have a video file whose resolution is 720x480, so the correct aspect ratio is 4:3, but when I play it, it is displayed in 16:9 ratio. I use MediaInfo to check the file and see that the Aspect Ratio metadata is 16:9, not 4:3.

Is there a way to change this metadata to 4:3?

Comment: How about mentioning the actual container (file extension) and video codec being used?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about editing the meta data but you can use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) to force an aspect ratio of 4:3.

You can do this in VLC by opening the video you want to play once the video is open in VLC:
`goto Video -> Aspect Ratio -> 4:3 or whatever ratio you would like`

I'm not sure what video player you are using currently but in my experience VLC is the best.

Comment: thanks, but I already know how to do this in media player classic